# RegEx: Check for char at the start of string

Tags: regex, string, delphi, char, match

**Some information:**

I've got a Delphi XE Regular Expression:

```
(?<=[*+\/drt><=≥≤≠])\-
```

Inputstring:

```
-(2*3)
```

The RegEx must match a '-' that makes an expression negative. So for example:

```
-(2*3) //Must Match
```

But not:

```
2 - 3 //Must not Match
```

In the example above, the operator works as a minus, it does not make the whole expression negative.

My solution for this is my regular expression above, it only matches a minus after an operator. It won't match if the char before the minus is an variable, number or some other defined keywords.

**My problem**

If the minus is at the start of the string, the regular expression does not match, because there is no char in front, even though the character makes the whole expression negative. How can I match this minus, even if it's at the beginning of the string and has no character in front?

Comment: Very hard to parse expressions with regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To match either start of string or a char inside the positive character class is

```
(?<=^|[*+/drt><=≥≤≠])-
    ^^
```

See the [online demo](https://regex101.com/r/YotsVN/1).

However, if you only deal with standalone strings, it is more efficient to convert the positive lookbehind withj a positive character class and an alternative to a negative lookbehind with a negative character class:

```
(?<![^*+/drt><=≥≤≠])-
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YotsVN/2). Only test one string after another, not all in a multiline mode.

Note you do not need to escape `-` outside a character class. No need to escape the `/` char either, it is not a special regex metacharacter, and you do not need to use it as a regex delimiter in Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe can you try?

```
(\-\().+(\))
```

Starts with "-(", any character, followed by ")".

Resulting...

```
-(2*3) //Must Match
2 - 3 //Must not Match
test -(2*3) //Must Match??
test -( 2*3 ) //Must Match??
test -() //Must not Match??
test -( ) //Must Match??
```